# Google's Text-To-Speech API - Security

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have a security question about Google's Text-To-Speech API or similar.  I want to build a simple app that takes pasted text and reads it back to you using TTS.  My security concern is sensitive data being translated off the local device.  Do you know if anything is ever sent to the Google servers (or similar) to read the text back to the use?

Comment: I am not sure what you want, but the only things you send using the API will be sent to the TTS API, for example, "hello world!". Unless you are sending sensitive data.

Comment: Quick test would be to turn off mobile network connection and try run your program, see if it works, it’s just using a library on the device then it should continue to work with no internet connection and you should be good from a security concern perspective

Comment: @Gary  that was my first thought by I didn't want to put everything together and need network to speak pasted words.

Comment: Sure yeah, makes sense. Looks like this has actually been asked previously, though not sure how convincing the answers are:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43486478/does-tts-api-work-without-network-connection-on-android

Comment: Everything will be sent. Check out their terms of service and privacy policy